# "Cyclic group" vs "primitive root" definition confusion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

Primitive root:
If $a^{h}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ is not possible for $ 1\le h \lt \phi(n)$, then $a$ is a primitive root of $n$.

Does this mean if $n$ has a primitive root, then a group of order $n$ is cyclic ?
Because we can use the primitive root to generate the entire group.

---

If my understanding so far is accurate, here is where I'm stuck at:
1) I read that if a group has order $pq$, where $p\gt q$ are primes and if $q\nmid p-1$, then the group is cyclic.
2) But I also know that a number of form $pq$ can not have a primitive root.

Aren't above two statements contradicting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\varphi (pq)=(p-1)(q-1)\lt pq$.

The existence of a primitive element  $\pmod n$ doesn't mean a group of size $n$ is cyclic.  It means the group of units $U_n$ (of size $\phi(n)$) is cyclic.

So there is no contradiction.  $U_{pq}$, the group of units of $\Bbb Z_{pq}$, is never cyclic.  But a group of order $pq$ can be cyclic (and is when $q\not\mid p-1$).

Comment: Chris wow so $n=pq$ has no primitive roots means that there is no cyclic group of size $(p-1)(q-1)$ ? I have been struggling with this all morning. Thank you so much I think I'm getting it finally XD

Comment: Great!  @rsadhvika. One detail.  There is of course a cyclic group of size $n$ for any $n$.  The fact you are referring to concerns the _group of units_.

Comment: Ohk.. If $n=pq$, then $U_n$ has size $(p-1)(q-1)$. This particular group cannot be cyclic as $n$ has no primitive roots. Amazing! I totally get it Thanks again have a nice day:)

Comment: You're welcome.   You too.